# What are the alternatives to denormalization in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Chapter 10.5 of Sasha Greif's [Discover Meteor](http://www.discovermeteor.com/) compares denormalisation in Meteor with the (more common) normalised data structures.

The example given is a list of posts with a comment count on each post.

Obviously you don't want the user subscribed to receive every post.  The solution used in the book is to denormalize the comment count onto every post.  Another solution discussed is a special Publication of only the comment count.

Is there another solution?  Couldn't you use a Meteor Method? Call it client-side and it runs server-side, where all the comments are known and therefore countable.

I'll guess that the answer is that this breaks the realtime qualities of the app.  Is that the only downside?  Is my suggestion even possible?

Comment: Is that chapter available online?  Couldn't find it.  Not having the book I'm not sure I exactly understand what you are asking.  What is preventing count from being a run-of-the mill reactive computation?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately it's not online. I think you're right, nothing is preventing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make another collection of counts and keep it in sync with your other crud operations.  That would not be denormalized, and would avoid thrashing the db.